# Some questions regarding Conditional Probability and hypothesis testing?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I know that P(B|A) = P(A and B) / P(A) by Bayes Rule, but what happens if A can vary across two values such as A = 1 and A = 0?
How then would I find P(B|A)?
Eg. If I had a scenario where

- P(B) = the probability of my test result where P(B=1) means my test results comes out positive and P(B=0) means my test result is negative
- P(A) = the prevalence of my disease where 1 indicates a prevalence and 0 means no disease

If I want to find the probability that my test results comes out positive given the  initial condition of my disease =  P(B = 1| A). How would I find this probability when A can take on the values of my disease being positive or negative?

Also if my first test comes out to be positive given the condition of my disease P(first test + | initial condition), would it make sense that the probability of my 2nd testing being positive given the condition of my disease P(2nd test + | initial condition) be the same since the result of the first test should be independent of my 2nd test given my initial condition?

Comment: When we write $P(B|A)$, we mean $A$ is already given, i.e., $A$ is fixed in computing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I want to find the probability that my test results comes out
> positive given the initial condition of my disease = P(B = 1| A). How
> would I find this probability when A can take on the values of my
> disease being positive or negative?

In this case you will have $P(B=1|A=0)$ and $P(B=1|A=1)$. Conditioning on $A$ means that you already know its realization.

> Also if my first test comes out to be positive given the condition of
> my disease P(first test + | initial condition), would it make sense
> that the probability of my 2nd testing being positive given the
> condition of my disease P(2nd test + | initial condition) be the same
> since the result of the first test should be independent of my 2nd
> test given my initial condition?

Cosider that if they are independent it must hold that, for any realizazion of $A=\{0,1\}$:

$$P(\text{1st test+ and 2nd test+} |A=a) = P(\text{1st test+} |A=a)P(\text{2nd test +} |A=a)$$

Comment: so then considering that it holds that they are independent for any realization of A, is there any way I can find P(2nd test + | first test +) without knowing which value A takes on eg. 0 or 1? also thanks, I think this answer helped clear some of my misunderstandings.

Comment: This really depends on the data you have. Consider that $P(\text{1st test +})=P(\text{1st test +} \cap A=0)+P(\text{1st test +} \cap A=1)$.